# How to safely browse internet in a business computer and network?

Tags: windows, networking, security

Let me specify.
I work as internal administrative software developer in a big business. The problem is: We have to use their workstations and their network is unlocked (Not firewalls, blocked urls, etc.)

What I want is to safely browse through internet without caring they know what I visited or if they are tracking what I'm visiting in the network. How can I do this?

I was thinking on creating a portable VM in an external drive and use it for browsing (So I don't worry about writing to the SSD with temp files).

Is there some way I can safely browse? Should I use Tor or something similar? A portable VM in an external drive to do whatever I want in it? How do I avoid they track what I'm visiting?
Consider not installing software, so portable solutions should be valid only.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear unclear - are you OK with "them" tracking what you are doing on the network, or are you wanting to browse safe from them tracking it ?  Also, you say they don't have a firewall or blocked URL's - if they don't have a firewall, how do you think they may be tracking you ? [ There is no way you can prevent them from tracking that you are using the Internet and seeing how much data is coming from your device, you may be able to hide what it is you are doing ]

Comment: No, I don't want the to track what I'm doing in the network and yeah, hide what I'm doing :3

Comment: I confess to flagging this question - I don't think it is appropriate to encourage this kind of behaviour - My view is it is both dumb (you will get caught out if they analyse their traffic or suspect anything)  and dishonest.   That said, the solutions are either ToR or a VPN on a USB VM - these will hide what you are doing, but not that you are doing something dodgy - if anything they will draw attention to you trying to cover up your actions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question appears to be no more then asking to steal Internet access from a trusting employer.

Comment: Or you judge at your own perception
Sometimes I send certain personal info transaction or bank transaction and I don't want to get sniffed or something by the network administrators lol

Comment: How quickly do you want to get fired? This is one of the faster methods.

Comment: @FUCXIFuczi - you talked about hiding your activities and and tracking what you are visiting rather then intercepting your comunications. (If your concern is really about banking, ask another question as the answer is very different because the threat model is different, and its about understanding how  https works). Tor provides anonymity more then security, and you have the issue of key loggers.

Comment: Questions about circumventing enterprise IT are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several notes:

1) Office PCs often are screen-monitored and (possibly) key-loggered. So, it doesnt matter if you do VPN/VIRTUALBOX/proxy etc... If your screen is being recorded, then you are visible to system. However, if this is not case for you, then:

2) It's better to avoid doing stuff on office PC (using their internet!), that may harm to office security system or cause problems with your company (as @JourneymanGeek mentioned). If you do legal stuff, and just want privacy&anonimity, then:

3) It's better to use your device-internet-tethering(like mobile-tether, as @JourneymanGeek mentioned too), then it may be the solution. If you cant do that, then:

4) VM could be one possible way, but only several ones (i.e. TOR OS), because other OS'es doesnt encrypt your actions (as far as i know), so you may be transparent. If you cant do that, then:

5)Better, portable versions of VPN or TOR BROWSER (though,some users may not recommend this).

- VPN (sys-admins probably cant see what you do)
- TOR (sys-admins probably cant see what you do, but they might detect that you use "TOR channel")

if the above doesnt help you, then:

6) If it's too important thing in your life, then just buy a secondary Laptop/Netbook, with a 4g modem, and relax.

Comment: ad 4: Perhaps you could omit that VM statement, that "It's same operating system (just inside operating system)." because it does not need to be this way. Check hypervisor topic for more info.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not doing illegal stuff, I just wanted privacy, that's all! Who in the world has a nice fresh work and want to do illegal stuff in it? I don't know why there are too much skeptical people here. I'm just talking about personal privacy, not about their illegal conspiracies lol
This question brought too much weird skeptical thinking here

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply, you don't. You don't put anything that's not part of the corporate network into a corporate network.

I was working in a place with no AUP. but had a content blocking system that blocked things rather arbitrarily. I didn't like it, but it was the cost of doing business.

In most well run places, an unknown PC turning up on their corporate network would set off all sorts of alarm bells, even if it work. In a *less well run place* I wouldn't use the PC they provide for anything remotely private.

So the answer is "use your own gear and tether it off your phone, or if you don't want work knowing about it" *Don't do it at work*.

Even in a permissive environment I didn't trust my office PC with my main username and password, since the system was not rebuilt between users. Pretty much there is no expectation of privacy on a shared or employer owned system or network, and your behaviour on such machines should reflect that.

I would note most IT security professionals would consider running tor or a liveusb on a corporate machine to get around the system to be something that death would be too good for.

Comment: Jaja it's not "something to death", it's just I don't trust so much the network in the work. I mean, it's really safe but there is no Wi-Fi (Well, there's public Wi-Fi for workers, less secure lol). In My workstation everything is by cable, so I would like to use the wired internet more than Wi-Fi but I don't like to browse my bank account and personal social media when I don't know what they do with that info, that's it. I want privacy :)

Comment: And I can't use the Ethernet cable unless it's a corporation machine, so using my laptop in that is not an option. I could use the Wi-Fi but I trust it less. We are less the ones who have a personal corporate machine so I trust more Ethernet but don't know what's going on with my privacy. That's why I asked for a tip

Comment: Guess I'll use portable VBox + Tor inside it

Comment: That is totally not what my answer says. Seriously. You shouldn't be running non work VMs or VPN type things on a office PC

Comment: From an end users POV, an ethernet connection should not be considered any more secure then an open WIFI as you have no control of the data. Thats what https and end-to-end VPNS protect. Using TOR in this case is worse then an open access point as your traffic is routed through an exit node which is more likely to be compromised then WIFI (better payload, more valuable content flowing through it). Using your own device over wifi/cell is absolutely the correct answer. No keyloggers and control of CAcerts. Also no problem with bank firewalls blocking exit node traffic to protect their network.